# change image SRC and Style

Tags: javascript, image, tags, url-rewriting

Hi I want to rewrite an image Src and Style element.
The image tag has an element called "data-orig-file" wich has the url that I want to write to the src element.
I came up with this but I'm not good at javascript:

```
function changeImageSrc(img) {
var newurl= document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('data-orig-file');
var oldurl= document.getElementById("img").src;
document.getElementById("img").src = img.src.replace(oldurl, newurl);
}
```

Now Secondly I want to grab the "Style" element with it's values from the grandparent div of the image and write that style to the image instead of the original style.

Finally I want to do these two things on all images inside a container div on a page when it is loaded (I suppose).

Any help is greatly apreciated!!

Thanks

update:

what I came up with so far is this:

```
function ChangeImageSrc() {
var image=document.getElementById("img");
var div=document.getElementById("LastPost");;

for each (image in div) {
var newurl= document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('data-orig-file');
var oldurl= document.getElementById("img").src;
document.getElementById("img").src = img.src.replace(oldurl, newurl);
}
}

window.onload = function()
            {
               ChangeImageSrc();
            };
```

I also tried it with an "onload" event on the body element like this (instead of the wondow.onload part):

```
onload="javascript:ChangeImageSrc()
```

Both don't work this far :(

Ok AffluentOwl, here's the HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-group images-1" style="width: 677px; height: 507px;">
<div class="tiled-gallery-item tiled-gallery-item-large">
<a href="http://i0.wp.com/www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/..../../image.jpg" class="zoom">
<img data-attachment-id="5786" data-orig-file="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/..../../image.jpg" data-orig-size="1333,1000"  data-medium-file="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/..../../image-300x225.jpg" data-large-file="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/..../../image-1024x768.jpg" src="http://i0.wp.com/www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/..../../image.jpg?resize=1191%2C893" align="left" title="shelter-childrens-farm" data-recalc-dims="1" style="width: 73px; height: 9px;">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a CDN prefix to the url that I'm trying to loose (for good reasons, it's opposed to me by wordpress and doesn't work for me).
The second thing is about the style of the image tag, that's somehow set to the wrong dimensions so I want to grab the right size from the first div (top of code).

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the HTML of the file you wish to modify? It looks like you're mixing up some terms like "attribute" and "element" so I'd like to better know your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you replace an images' `src` attribute with a url stored in an attribute on the image called `data-orig-file` when the page loads.

```
<html>
    <script>
    function ChangeImageSrc() {
        var div = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-group images-1")[0];
        var images = div.getElementsByTagName("img");

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].setAttribute("src", images[i].getAttribute("data-orig-file"));
            images[i].setAttribute("style", div.getAttribute("style"));
        }
    }

    window.onload = ChangeImageSrc;
    </script>

    <div class="gallery-group images-1" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
        <div class="tiled-gallery-item tiled-gallery-item-large">
            <img src="a.jpg" data-orig-file="b.jpg" id="image_id" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
            <img src="c.png" data-orig-file="d.jpg" id="image_id" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
            <img src="e.png" data-orig-file="f.png" id="image_id" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

It would probably be helpful for you to look into the element selection functions in Javascript.

- [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementById)
- [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByClassName)
- [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByTagName)
- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector)

You may even like to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which makes [selecting elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) much easier. In jQuery you could replace the <script> code with the following for the same result as above:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var div = $(".gallery-group.images-1");
    var images = div.find("img");

    images.each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-orig-file"));
        $(this).attr("style", div.attr("style"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi AffluentOwl, Thanks for the help !! The snippet you provided did somehow not work though when placed in the head. What I want to do is replace the CDN url with the regular url, this can also be done by just stripping the CDN added prefix I found later! I would do that like this `document.getElementById("img").src = img.src.replace(array('i2.wp.com/','i1.wp.com/'), '');
` as you can see I'm trying to loose the wordpress photon cdn that doesn't work properly for me, however with this snippet I get an error that says: `Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash `

Comment: Oh, no sorry that was an error from a php file with the same purpose. I do sometimes default to php as I never seem to get any rewriting done with js snippets...

Comment: @MichielvanDijk I've updated my answer with your HTML structure. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Hi AffluentOwl, Thanks very much!! that's a great working piece of code!! The only problem that remains is that I want to do this on all the images in a certain page container div (witch contains the .gallery-group div's with images inside them). What happens now is that only the first image gets a src and style rewrite. Do you have any idea? Thanks this far!

Comment: I've updated the code to demonstrate how to loop over multiple images. The `getElementsByTagName` function returns an array of all the elements it matches. When there was only a single image, I indexed into this array to grab the first image with `getElementsByTagName("img")[0]`. Now my code shows a for loop over all the images in the first example, and shows how to use the `each` function in the jQuery example.

Comment: Hi AffluentOwl, Thanks very much!! That works for all the images (the first snippet), great! Now I would rather use the jQuery bit but should there also be a `window.onload` bit to that? (or something similar) or does the jQuery bit work like this out of the box when put in the head?

Comment: Ok, i tried putting the jQuery in like above and that works too!! The only thing that doesn't work (I changed it a bit) is the style rewrite, my code looks like this for that part:     `$(this).attr("style","width:100%;height:100%;");` that is cause I found out that the parent div doesn't always carry the right styles (so I can't grab them from there and copy them to the image).

Comment: Well to be honest I'm still struggling a bit, I want to set the height and width of the image or at least one of those and the other to auto, here's what I came up with: [link](http://pastebin.com/9CbZJHS3) it seems to work but somethimes it only works when I reload the page. the thing is that the html is very unstructured with this gallery so sometimes there are two images inside a div so you can only grab the smallest width/height cause that is the width of the image as well (height is then set to auto). Sometimes you have to get the style from the grandparent div. Do you see errors?